# Crankshaft position system variation not learned p0315

Tags: engine

08 Chevy Malibu starts and stalls scanner shows crankshaft position system variation not learned how can I fix this. This engine was running strong not 48 hours ago put in different car now it's showing this p0315 code?

Comment: Have you checked that the sensor is properly connected? Not loose or broken..

Comment: Yes it's on tight. I can hear it clip on. The plug seems to be clean all three of the turminals a shiny.

Comment: Oh if I put the gas pedal to the floor it will stay running and just keep hitting the red line till I let off the pedal then it stalls out

Answer (score 1):

The p0315 code has nothing to do with the start stall. The PCM lost the variation and it needs to be relearned. This has more to do with the PCMs ability to detect misfires. Another time you’d want to do a variation relearn is after repairing a misfire fault, timing work or high RPM false misfires.

With a scantool and engine temp > 158 degrees F.  Select the variation relearn function in your scantool (tech 2/gds or other). Set the parking brake. Key On Engine Running press the gas pedal until the car hits fuel cut. If everything went well the variation is learned-there will be a pass/fail message-and you can clear the code.

For the stalling, make sure the throttle plate is clean and moves freely, perform an idle relearn with an above mentioned scantool.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that after work today and see what happens

Comment: I have a genisys 4.0 and don't know where to look to do the crankshaft position system variation relearn procedure

Comment: I’m only used to snapon software or oe in some cases. Look for bidirectional controls it’ll be in there somewhere if your software supports it. On snapon software it’s listed under engine functional tests. Might be similar.

Comment: So I figured out how to do the crank relearn procedure did it five six times every time I shut the car off though it would forget it. I did drive it for a half an hour or more and then shut it off and still forgot everything. I can start the car up and run it for 5 minutes rubbing it up and down to keep it from stalling after 5 minutes it'll run time only code that pops up in the scanner is a mass air flow code but then you shut the car off and it still the crank position system variation needs to be learned. Any thoughts.

Comment: @craigs do you have a scope I’d like to see a complete pattern. Can you verify that the teeth on the crank reluctor are the same from the engine you swapped? Can you expand on the stalling a bit more? Is the engine misfiring whether you feel it or not? Is the PCM recording misfires as you try to do the ckp variation? Also try disconnecting the battery and shorting the cable ends together for a few minutes as a last resort.

Comment: Yah it's misfiring 50 misfires in the first 5 min but after that Everytime it will run just fine I can check the codes it has when I'm out driving it and it only shows one code and that's fuel trim is lean. It runs perfect no hesitation no stamor it's perfect.

Comment: I don't have a scope I returned everything to my buddy last night. I put the computer in the the car that came with the engine. It acts the same with booth computers.

Comment: Is there a wire that goes to the ECM that is constant power.

Comment: @craigs if it’s a 5v ref (it probably is) yes and low ref and sig.